# How do I stop text fields and picked images vanishing when device is turned off

Tags: ios, singleton, photo

My text fields and my images picked from image picker all reset set blank if my app stops running, or device is turned off, How can I retain this information?

I've used a singleton (with help from a fellow member) and I can retain my image...that is until the app is killed or device is turned off. Then it's gone.

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    singletonObj = [Singleton sharedSingletonController];
    imageView.image = singletonObj.imagePicked;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setImageView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
     return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
 }

 #pragma mark - Action

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}

- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info

{
    NSData  *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],1);

    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:dataImage];
    singletonObj.imagePicked = img;
    imageView.image = img;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of memory: volatile (RAM) and permanent memory (ie: hard drives and other storage).

Volatile memory is cleared and lost when a program/computer shuts down.

Using a singleton is fine but it's completely unrelated to keeping data from session to session (and by *session* I mean the time when the program is running:  from launch to termination of an application).

You need to store data you wish to keep from session to session to file using any method you want.  Depending on the information you want to store, there are different dedicated mechanism for saving:

- (such as [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults) for user preferences).
- [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/) is a framework which defines mechanism for structuring data and saving/reading it to file (a.k.a. persistent store).
- You can also use [serialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).
- Or you can always manually manipulate files.
- [`NSData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata) has [`writeToFile:atomically:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1408033-writetofile) which will write create a file out of a data object.  If you want to save an image, you must obtain an UIImage's underlying data (i.e.: [`UIImagePNGRepresentation(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1624096-uiimagepngrepresentation)).

Comment: In your opinion what would be the best option for storing one single image picked from camera roll?

Comment: If all you ever care about is storing one image (i.e. subsequent picks replace the previously chosen image), I'd write that image out to a file in your app's documents directory. There are convenience functions for getting PNG or JPEG data out of a `UIImage`, and if you only have one image you can always keep it at the same path.

Comment: @rickster true! Expanded on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use core data. It can accept NSData from a UIIimage as well as NSStrings. The function within the appDelegate, AppicationWillTerminate, will have to use so that the information is stored just before the application is terminated.

This is going to require some decent amount of work to get it working properly, but nothing too difficult. If you need help understanding core data, I recommend this link

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: That's the only option?  what about if I just wanted to retain the  photoI've read that tut before and found it past my skills set at the moment.

Comment: Anything that is retained in memory will be removed one the application is terminated. Therefore, it must be saved to the disk in some form. Core Data may be a little difficult, but trust me, I thought the same before I used it.  It really isn't that bad once you get the hang of it.